# Email Template Folder not found error while creating 2GP package version

Tags: managed-package, email-template, folder

I am trying to create 2GP managed package via Salesforce CLI using sfdx commands however when I run `sfdx force:package:version:create` command I get the following errors related to the email template folder and email templates which are already included in my package :

1. {FolderName} : To create email template folders, enable Folders and Enhanced Sharing.
2. {FolderName}/{TemplateName} : Cannot find folder:{FolderName}
3. {FolderName}/{TemplateName} : Cannot find folder:{FolderName}
4. {FolderName}/{TemplateName} : Cannot find folder:{FolderName}
5. {FolderName}/{TemplateName} : Cannot find folder:{FolderName}

Here is the folders xml file  **FolderName.emailFolder-meta.xml** inside the package :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmailTemplateFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <name>{Folder Label}</name>
</EmailTemplateFolder>
```

Could someone please explain what could it be wrong here ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Double check you are not suppressing the folder and its content via `.forceignore`.

Comment: Hello @PhilW I checked but the folder is not referenced there. I am using my PBO to create package, before this wasn't an issue when the org was in trial but after they activated the org somehow I started to get this error

Comment: When you say using your PBO, do you simply mean your PBO is set as your Dev Hub? If so, double check that it is still active in that way (a PBO provides completely different limits to a Developer org-based Dev Hub). Probably worth asking Salesforce Support.

Comment: Yes Dev Hub is enabled in my PBO @PhilW I am just trying to make sure that if it is sth related to my orgs configuration

Comment: The Dev Hub configuration is irrelevant as long as it has the namespace registered with it and you have granted license for your user to manage scratch orgs. 2GP does not use any pre-existing org as the packaging org (the packaging org is transiently created while creating package versions), so it is your `sfdx-project.json` and file system (specifically the package's `packageDirectory` structure) that controls the content of your package. You need to be sure you have the metadata all in that `packageDirectory` structure and not excluded by `.forceignore`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details including the basic folder structure of your project and the `sfdx-project.json` content.

Comment: Hello @PhilW I edited the question, please let me know if this is enough